# How to fill soil void along basement wall?

Tags: water, basement, waterproofing, drainage, downspout

The previous homeowners did not keep up with the downspouts and some erosion occurred.  All of the drains to the street are great and I have reconnected the downspouts to the drain pipes; some were apart my multiple inches when I dug them up under the downspout, right against the house.  All small leaks have stopped in the basement except for one.  I have a poured foundation.

In my front corner of the house, the water had eroded a tunnel about the size of my arm, along the exterior of the basement wall, at about a 45 degree angle for about two yards, and then it goes straight down.  I collapsed the tunnel about 2 feet down with a spud bar and that has helped, but with heavy rains, water collects in that void and it comes in the basement.  The pressure is very small compared to before as it used to squirt into the basement a few feet like squirt gun!

I know I can buy a kit that involves drilling holes from the interior and fills the void on the exterior side of the wall, but could I pour something in the void from the top of the exterior side?  I wished I would have tackled this when I had it dug up about two feet down.  I was thinking just a a thin concrete mix would help but now I am wondering if their is a pourable foam product I could use... or just get one of those aforementioned kits.

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this but the only good way to stop a leak is from the outside. Cleaning the foundation and sealing it. When I do this kind of work I usually build a sump pit and back fill the walls with rock so the runoff drains into the pit. If there is still leakage on the walls  a pump in the pit usually will take care of it. I don't like cutting through the floor to create the pit but many people do.

Comment: I already have a sump pit and a pump.